# Use MatPlotLib to plot line graph with error ranges around points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a line graph of ten values with error ranges over each point:

```
u = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
plt.errorbar(range(10), u, yerr=1)
plt.show()
```

I get the error message

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Can someone please advise me the best way to plot a line graph with error bars over each point? http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plt.errorbar` expects the errors to have the same dimension as the x- and y-values (either a list of 2-tuples for up/down errors or a simple list for symmetric errors).

You want to do something like

```
u = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
plt.errorbar(range(10), u, yerr=[1]*10)
```

or more clearly with numpy imported as `np`

```
u = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
plt.errorbar(np.arange(10), u, yerr=np.ones(10))
```

Comment: this is also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598569/python-matplotlib-errorbar-issue

Comment: Note that the stackoverflow way of saying *Thank you* is accepting helpful answers which you should consider if you want to continue receiving answers to your questions.